# VB6: what's wrong with this tsql procedure call?

Tags: vb6, ado

I have the following procedure call in VB6:

```
dim rs as adodb.command 
dim cnn as adodb.connection 

with rs
    set .activeconnection = cnn 
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    .CommandText = "sp_qryUpdate" 
    .CommandTimeout = 0 
    .Parameters("@uidbatch").value = lngBatchID 
    .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords 
end with
```

I receive the error of,

> Object variable or with block variable not set

The error is thrown after the `.activeconnection` is set

Any ideas what this means? The connection string I'm receiving is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, `rs` is normally used to indicate a record set rather than a command but to each their own, I guess.

I see some potential issues. I'm not entirely certain of the difference since my exposure to VB6 was pleasantly brief but all the code I did had:

```
dim rs as new adodb.recordset
```

in it (i.e., with the `new` keyword). That may be causing a problem.

I also assume you have some code between that second `dim` and the `with`, yes?

Because otherwise, you're not actually *opening* a connection for use.

There's some tutorial code [here](http://www.timesheetsmts.com/adotutorial.htm) which may be of assistance. I'd say "Enjoy!" but I don't think that's an option :-)

Comment: that was what i forgot.. the "new" and .open statements.  now it stops at .Parameters("@uidbatch").value = lngBatchID with the error:  Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you must create an instance of the `adodb.command` and `adodb.connection` before of use it.

try this

```
dim rs as New adodb.command 
dim cnn as New adodb.connection
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the rs and the cnn as the others say, but also you need to add a new parameter to the parameters collection.

```
.Parameters("@uidbatch").value
```

This assumes that it exists already.

Comment: are you saying i need to add .Parameters.Append .createparameter("@uidbatch", adinteger, adparainput, , lngbatchid)?

Comment: yes I believe so. I've not done vb for years but it looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that manual parameter definition, but it's much easier to just use rs.Parameters.Refresh.  That will correctly populate the parameters collection automatically.

Also, while it is correct that you have to instantiate the object variables, doing it on the same line is not to be recommended.  Unlike in .Net, this does not actually instantiate the variable.  Rather, every time the variable is referenced, the runtime checks to see if an instance exists and creates one if not.  This creates unnecessary overhead.  Best practice is to use the Set keyword on a new line.